# SVG.JS append or prepend transformation

Tags: svg, raphael

I'm using svg.js and svg.import.js to draw an svg image. I try to animate some elements using the animation functions. I have no idea how to append a transformation on an existing transformation. This is my element in the SVG file:

```
<g id="g5600" style="display:inline;" transform="matrix(0.64633527,-0.76305355,0.76305355,0.64633527,-257.64528,53.75293)">...</g>
```

When I try for example:

```
store.g5600.animate(2000).rotate(45);
```

The result is:

```
<g id="g5600" style="display:inline;" transform="rotate(45,155.6640625,382.421875)">...</g>
```

Where I want te result to be (exsiting matrix + rotation):

```
<g id="g5600" style="display:inline;" transform="matrix(0.64633527,-0.76305355,0.76305355,0.64633527,-257.64528,53.75293) rotate(45,155.6640625,382.421875)">...</g>
```

I have tried this code and it works, but I think this is not the best solution.

```
store.g5600.transform('matrix', '0.64633527,-0.76305355,0.76305355,0.64633527,-257.64528,53.75293').animate(2000).rotate(45);
```

So my question is how to append (or prepend) transformations.
By the way, I think in Raphael this is done by using:

```
el.transform("...t50,50");
el.transform("s2...");
```

Comment: After importing, does `store.g5600` still have its matrix transformation?

Comment: Ok, I see what is going on. The import plugin does not convert transformations, it just applies transformations as an attribute without parsing them.The import plugin is very much a work in progress, I implement features when they are necessary.

Comment: When I log this: `console.log(store.g5600.attr("transform"));` the result is: `matrix(0.64633527,-0.76305355,0.76305355,0.64633527,-257.64528,53.75293)`. The result of `console.log(store.g5600.transform());` is an initial object (values set to 0 or 1, etc.)

Comment: I'll have a look at it today, it is not too hard to implement it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [svg.import.js](https://github.com/wout/svg.import.js) plugin has now been updated to parse transformations. So this issue should be resolved. Please let me know how it goes.